# Hive with Tez, No input paths specified in job

Tags: hive, hadoop2, apache-tez

I have used hadoop-0.20.x.x, hive-0.11.0. I would talk about hive queries: with the specified configuration every thing is good and working fine.
Now, we have upgraded to hadoop-2.6.x (hadoop2)and hive-0.14.x. Also using Apache Tez.

The problem is, hadoop works as is. But hive sql queries doesn't.
The below query works fine in the older version's. But throw errors in the upgraded version's:
QUERY : `SELECT abc.property_name, xyz.date, xyz.time, xyz.value_as_number, xyz.value_units FROM dbname.xyz JOIN dbname.abc ON (xyz.id = abc.src_id) WHERE xyz.person_id=138312;`

EXCEPTION:

```
INFO  : Session is already open
INFO  : Tez session was closed. Reopening...
INFO  : Session re-established.
INFO  :

INFO  : Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1435524970199_0035)

INFO  : Map 1: -/-      Map 2: -/-
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1435524970199_0035_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1435524970199_0035_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: concept initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1435524970199_0035_1_00 [Map 1], java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getInputPaths(HiveInputFormat.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:130)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:245)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 2, vertexId=vertex_1435524970199_0035_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1435524970199_0035_1_01 [Map 2] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: observation initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1435524970199_0035_1_01 [Map 2], java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getInputPaths(HiveInputFormat.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:130)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:245)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:239)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]
ERROR : DAG failed due to vertex failure. failedVertices:2 killedVertices:0
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask (state=08S01,code=2)
```

Exception says, `No input path specified`. Well, i understand and know how to do solve in haodop-mapreduce program. But, how do we do it using hive query. Anyway, i don't think this is the same.

To make out, i have used `hive shell` and `beeline shell`, hive returned expected output but, beeline returned the same exception as above.

The beauty of the problem is query on individual table works fine. But, when i try to work on the `JOIN`, it throws the above exception.
But, i have understood that, there's an impact of `Apache Tez` on my query. Can some one suggest the solution or pin point tez reference, so i could read and rewrite the query accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked by disabling `apache tez`. 
Look's like `apache tez` isn't stable yet.